# Organizing a Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp

In my application I have 2 tables in the DB (MySQL):
`Companies` and `News`. `Company` has many `News`.

`Company` can have a set of pictures which will be displayed on the `company` "view page" alongside with all relative information about this company.

I've added a `Photos` table with next fields: `id` `company_id` `filename`

My question is: Now I also need to have pictures which will belong to `News`.
I should add another table, which will be called for example `Media` or I should add additional field (`type`) to my `Photos` table, rename `company_id` to `foreign_id` and then filter results in PHP and build more complex queries with for example `AND 'type' = 1` to fetch photos related to Company and 'type = 2' to fetch photos related to `news`.

What is a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take the `company_id` field out of the `Photos` table and create two new tables, `CompanyPhotos` with `id`, `photo_id`, `company_id` fields, and another `NewsPhotos` with `id`, `photo_id`, `news_id`.

Then if you want to get the photos for a company you can do: `select * from Photos p inner join CompanyPhoto cp on p.id = cp.photo_id where cp.company_id = ?`.

And similary with `NewsPhoto`: `select * from Photos p inner join NewsPhoto np on p.id = np.photo_id where np.news_id = ?`.

Comment: Don't you think this approach is a bit overkill for what I need? Because I have two simple X hasmany Y relationship. And question is – do I need to have 2 different tables or 1 table for all will be ok..

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 2 or 1 table. There are 3 tables already: `Photos`, `Company` and `News`. Your question is about how to join `Photos` to both `Company` and `News`, but neither of the possible solutions you gave are correct. Having a whole copy of `Photos` (1st idea) means as soon as you need one photo related to both `News` and `Company` you will have duplication of data (i.e. same photo in `Photos` and `Media`). Using a `type` field to determine the table linked to (2nd idea) is breaking the whole point of using an RDBMS - you will never have any actual referential integrity.

Comment: Sorry, maybe my English is not allowing me to accurately convey information. I never need to have one photo related to both `News` and `Company`

Comment: Well, I wouldn't be so certain that that the photos will never be shared. Requirements have a habit of changing like that. Another reason why it is better to put all the photos in one table instead of two, is, let's say in the future you want to record a caption for photos, or the date of the photo, etc, your way would have to add a field to two different tables instead of one, and modify twice as much code.  I personally don't think of the joiner tables as being complex at all rather just a standard method. Even if it exceeds requirements, I think it is still the most correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is always good to [normalize databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). In the beginning it was just about tables with all data and it has evoluted to linked tables with common fields.

Hence, I strongly recommend you to have the table `Photos`.

After all, you have to make the basic question: can a photo belong to different news? Can a news have different pictures? If both questions' answer is "yes", you have a N:M relation, which is resolved with a middle table containing an id from every table.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand you right. I should go with 1 table for all pictures and with a `type` field in it? To clarify things: `Company` can have many photos. News also can have many photos. News and Companies don't share photos. So 1 `Company` = many unique photos and 1 `News` also = many unique photos related to the current news post, photos will not be shared between different `News`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `UUIDs` as your primary key. Because they are unique application-wide (if you create them with CakePHP), you could just use a `parent_id` column in your Photos table and get rid of the `type` colum.

Another approach would be MySQL Views. You could setup 2 Views (e.g. NewsPhotos, CompanyPhotos) on top of the Photos table. CakePHP handles (simple) Views like tables, so you could create easily Models & Controllers for this.